# Auto-inputing ssh password in shell scripts on Linux

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh, expect

I can use ssh command and provide password and connect to another server. But I need to pass password in the shell script. how?

Comment: Poor Mr. Torvalds.

Answer (score 2):

For this you should use the `sshpass` application which should be available from your distribution's package manager.

Once installed you can set the ssh password to use from the command line, where `uname -a` is the command you want to run.

`sshpass -p 'yourpassword' ssh youruser@yourhost 'uname -a'`